# Selected column Z:Z to replace formula but also replaces formula in column Q:Q Why?

Tags: excel, vba

Subtotaling two columns then using find replace for column Z also replaces formula in column Q.
How can I restrict it to only column Z? I've tried to use select visible cells but it still changes column Q.

```
Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=11, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(17, 26) _
    , Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
Columns("Z:Z").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Cells.Replace What:="SUBTOTAL(9", Replacement:="SUBTOTAL(1", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: My guess is that Q is referencing values that you are changing.

Answer (score 1):

`Cells.Replace` refers to all cells in the active worksheet. use `Columns("Z").Replace`.